# Mobile view misplacement

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

profit website for an organisation.

this is the link [www.notevayaslionel.com](http://www.notevayaslionel.com)

Website is great in desktop however when you go mobile you can see that apparently the image in the background is bigger than the window screen and you can scroll sideways.

How con I solve this? I dont want any sideway scrolling.

This is my CSS:

```
/*  Parallax Background ==================================================*/
#parallax {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    position:fixed;
    background-image:url(https://trancazos.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/las-redes-sociales-a-messi-no-te-vayas-lio.jpg?w=1024);
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

Comment: its the iframe that is causing width to expand to 500px , and there are multiple places of setting width

Comment: Hello yes Im trying to set the Iframe width but I cant set it as the script has a function that inserts that iframe, therefore I cant actually edit it.

Comment: @TomasAlonsoRehor great website by the way, please make it responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your styles . It will make your website responsive:

```
#centeralign iframe {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 500px;
}
```